# CSS adding two blocks on same line

Tags: html, css

I want to create box like this:

[image]

But with my current code I am getting something like this:
[image]

Here is my current code

```css
<Note_firstpart style="display: inline;background:#31B458; background: -moz-linear-gradient(#31B458 , #1BC14D); background: -o-linear-gradient(#31B458 , #1BC14D); background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#31B458 , #1BC14D); background: linear-gradient(#31B458 , #1BC14D); border: 1px solid #05500b; padding: 9px;">
</Note_firstpart>
<Note_body style="display:inline-block; background:#DDFFED; background: -moz-linear-gradient(#DDFFED , #BBFEDA); background: -o-linear-gradient(#DDFFED , #BBFEDA); background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#DDFFED , #BBFEDA); background: linear-gradient(#DDFFED , #BBFEDA); border: 1px solid #05500b; padding: 11px;">
Long Text</Note_body>
```

Comment: I want to use this for blogger. I wish to create .note class type then will access or call it everything it needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution, which will give you a really clean markup, is to use a pseudo element.

With that you can either use Flexbox or any other way to size and color it, here done with absolute position and a padding.

```css
/* Note Box
-----------------------------------------*/

    .note_text {
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin-left: 10px;
      background: #FFFFFF;
      padding: 3px 3px 3px 25px;
    }
    
    .note_text::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0; left: 0;
      bottom: 0; width: 20px;
      border-right: 1px solid black;
      background: #23E67E; 
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="note_text">
      Test seeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
      NEW LINE TESTING TESTING
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

use flexbox for that.

Note I changed your `<note` tag to `div`

```css
section {
  display: flex
}

div {
  border: 1px solid #05500b;
  padding: 11px;
}

div:first-of-type {
  background: linear-gradient(#31B458, #1BC14D);
  flex: 0 100px;
}

div:last-of-type {
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div> </div>
  <div> Long Text</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Ahh beat me to it. I do like to give this link when using flexbox as an answer just to help provide reference of all the other abilities it has. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: By adding this code on Blogger CSS section,but its making the whole page looks like this. So customized it using .section and .div but that didn't worked too.  Also tried adding this code on html section of the page still didn't worked. But thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .outer {
      border: 1px solid black;
      height: auto;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    .inner {
      border-left: 1px solid black;
      height: auto;
      margin-left: 25px;
      background-color: white;
      text-indent: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      Tesxt
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I just used two divs where they're the same height but the inner's margin is shifted to the left and the text is also indented with a border on the left only and the outer has a border. You can just change the colours to suit you.

Comment: Adding a width at the .inner section worked. I set all width & height to auto

Comment: Wonderful! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Note_body style="display:inline-block; background:#DDFFED; background: -moz-linear-gradient(#DDFFED , #BBFEDA); background: -o-linear-gradient(#DDFFED , #BBFEDA); background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#DDFFED , #BBFEDA); background: linear-gradient(#DDFFED , #BBFEDA); border: 1px solid #05500b;height:40px;width:150px;line-height:40px;">
    <Note_firstpart style="display: inline;background:#31B458; background: -moz-linear-gradient(#31B458 , #1BC14D); background: -o-linear-gradient(#31B458 , #1BC14D); background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#31B458 , #1BC14D); background: linear-gradient(#31B458 , #1BC14D); border: 1px solid #05500b;padding:11px;margin-right:10px;">
    </Note_firstpart>
        Long Text
</Note_body>
```

> this code is display like this

[image]

Comment: Its not working only the 1st two word of the whole sentence showing inside   the block not the whole text, whole text showing outside.

Comment: If you want to more text in _Node_body_ Plase increase `width:350px;` or `width:600px;` of  **Note_body**

Answer (score 0):

You should use [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

I hope this would suffice

```css
  .parent {
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
  }
  div:not(.parent) {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #0E0E0E;
  }
  .color {
    background: linear-gradient(#31B458, #1BC14D);
    flex: 0 20%;
  }
  .text {
    flex: 1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="color">

  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```